# How to open a chrome extension programatically from a website?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, metamask

I want to trigger the popup/opening of a chrome extension programatically from a website. Metamask (browser wallet) is doing exactly this when you navigate to a website and press the button "connect to metamask". In fact it's not actually opening the extension like when pressing the extension icon, but it opens a new browser window with the same size loading the extension...
Any idea how to achieve this?

Comment: Your extension should listen to [a message from the web page](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging#external-webpage), then open the popup window.

Comment: Did you find a definitive answer for that?

Answer (score 0):

Here's the way I found meanwhile:

- post a message from the website to itself via `window.postMessage()`
- content script has an event listener and catches this message
- content script sends another message to the service worker (aka background script)
- background script has a message listener and creates a new window via `chrome.windows.create(<url-to-extension-html>, <height-and-with-same-as-extension>)`